# Отслеживание курсора Javascript

Tags: javascript

Как можно отследить, находится ли курсор над определенным элементом?

Comment: например: [event mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо подключить к элементу слушателя на событие `mouseover`, например так, если с jquery:

```
$("element_selector").on("mouseover", function(e){
 // любой код
})
```

если на чистом js:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').onmousemove = function(e){ 
 // любой код
}
```

Про события мыши можно почитать здесь [Вот тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-details) (на русском)

Comment: в вопросе не было упоминания jQuery.

Comment: Если без jquery, то можно так: `document.getelementById('elementId').onmousemove = function(e){ // любой код}`

Comment: Вынесете этот код в ответ. P. S. он не рабочий.

Comment: внес рабочий, спасибо!)

Comment: @Mikl, почему в примере с jQuery _mouseover_, а без - _mousemove_?

Comment: Для разнообразия) mouseover - срабатывает один раз, когда мышка попадет на элемент, а mousemove будет вызываться много раз, пока мышка ездит по элементу. Вот.

Comment: @Mikl, стоит добавить это описание в ответ. Что произойдет если мышка будет над элементом _вложенным_ в наблюдаемый элемент?

Comment: Вспомните о `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`.

Comment: Если в наблюдаемый элемент вложен еще какой-нибудь элемент, то при переходе window->наблюдаемый элемент->вложенный элемент mouseover вызовется два раза, причем в объекте события поменяется target, mousemove продолжит вызываться и у нее тоже поменяется target. Вот можно в это [поиграть](https://jsfiddle.net/mx0b4ayk/)

Comment: @Mikl, это все должно быть в ответе

Comment: Это слишком жирно для такого вопроса))

Comment: @Mikl, в самый раз, иначе сейчас это просто два куска кода, причем разных, причем непонятно что делающих и чем отличающихся в поведении

Answer (score 0):

Вариант если уже подписаны на `mousemove` -

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', document_mouseMoveHandler);

function document_mouseMoveHandler(event) {
  let element = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
  let isSecondValid = isSecond(element.dataset.id);

  let info = document.querySelector('.validator-output')
  info.textContent = isSecondValid;
}

function isSecond(value) {
  return value === "second"
}
```

```css
main {
  padding: 15px
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
.informer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.child > span {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="child" data-id="first"><span>first</span>
      </div>
      <div class="child" data-id="second"><span>second</span>
      </div>
      <div class="child" data-id="third"><span>third</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="informer">
      <span>is second: <span class="validator-output">false</span></span>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: а если не подписаны?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text.onmouseover = function(){
  this.style.color = 'red'; //курсор над элементом
}
text.onmouseleave = function(){
  this.style.color = '#000';//курсор покинул элемент
}
```

```css
p{
 font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p id="text" >Some text</p>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.